# Negative sign appears on right side of number in Edit Box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried every possible solution and I cannot figure out how to set the minus sign to the left side of the number

I tried changing regional settings in Windows, everything is set to US English, nowhere in My OS does this happen

I tried running the project on other PCs but it still shows on the other side.

I tried changing the alignment, but in both cases it is still on the other side, as shown in the picture below

```
        aMoveABSmm.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
```

Localizable property is set to False, RTL is set to No, I tried changing all of these but the negative sign is always on the wrong side

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simple, one of the panels under the controls had RTL alignment set to True